# Alternative to .tabs("add", link, title) with new jQuery and jQuery-ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

In Microsoft's video "Javascript fundamentals 7- hours" in lesson 17 "Installing and Utilizing jQuery Plugins" starting at 05:28:20 in the link:

https://youtu.be/JTpjqYjrPyU?t=5h28m20s

it's described how to implement tabs using jQuery and jQuery-UI.  The abbreviated HTML source code is:

```
<div class="demo">
  <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
       <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
       <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
     </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Latin text 1 .... </p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Latin text 2 .... </p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Latin text 3A .... </p><p>Latin text 3B .... </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the video was made around 2012 using older versions of jQuery and jQuery-UI.  Most of the time this isn't much of a problem, but in the video a dynamic tab is added using the code:

```
$(function() {
  $("#tabs").tabs().tabs("add", "C9JS_16_html", "Click-a-bob");
});
```

Unfortunately, the method tabs("add", link, title) is no longer valid in the versions of jQuery1.12.0 and jQuery-UI.1.11.4 that I'm using.

I looked at the link:

http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#deprecated-add-and-remove-methods-and-events-use-refresh-method

and tried using it without much success.  I can get the code:

```
$(function() {
  $('li:last').append('<li><a href="C9JS_16.html">Click-a-bob</a></li>');
});
```

to insert a link in the HTML DOM after:

```
<li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
```

but it just shows up as a regular link in a list, and I'm unable to get it styled to appear as a new tab using .tabs() in that line of code.

Does anybody know how to fix this?  I would be most grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1):

hope will get you started:

```js
// The NEW Tab link
$("<li><a href='#tabs-4'>New Tab</a></li>").appendTo("#tabs .ui-tabs-nav");
// The NEW related Tab Content
$("<div id='tabs-4'><p>Latin text 4 .... </p></div>").appendTo("#tabs");



// Initiate UI Tabs
$("#tabs").tabs();
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div id="tabs">
  
  <ul class="ui-tabs-nav">
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>
  
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Latin text 1 .... </p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Latin text 2 .... </p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Latin text 3A .... </p><p>Latin text 3B .... </p>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: The addNewTab version works, but I could not get the 2nd one to work, but that is good enough - Many thanks.

Comment: I know this discussion doesn't belong here, but just to say it, add() was really useful, as was the url() method to set a tab's URL, also removed. Being consistent with other widget APIs is good, but IMO not at the expense of making people roll their own really common low-level functionality. Also, it seems likely that at least some other widgets also need similar tools, so implementing them there too would have also resulted in a consistent API, where it applied.

Answer (score 0):

You may always extend jQuery with a new function like addNewTab:

```js
$.fn.addNewTab = function (name, title, content) {
  $('ul', this).append('<li><a href="#tab-' + name + '">' + title + '</a></li>');
  $(this).append("<div id='tab-" + name + "'>" + content + "</div>");
  $(this).tabs("refresh");
};


$(function () {
  $("#tabs").tabs().addNewTab("C9JS_16_html", "Click-a-bob", 'some text');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div class="demo">
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1">
            <p>Latin text 1 .... </p>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-2">
            <p>Latin text 2 .... </p>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-3">
            <p>Latin text 3A .... </p><p>Latin text 3B .... </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, in fact I found that the 1st reply isn't exactly correct.  When you click on the "Click-a-bob" tab, you do get the content text displayed with that tag, but the name argument in the function isn't working correctly, so when you mouse-over the "Click-a-bob" tag, the link: ...C9JS_17.html#tab-C9JS_16.html is displayed at the bottom of the browser, rather than just C9JS_16.html, so it doesn't take you to that page on clicking the link.

In fact in the video the tabs are still shown on the original page, with the contents of C9JS_16.html shown below it.  It looks as if some type of iframe or some other include may be needed, so would appreciate some advice on this.

However, in the interim I made the following changes to the code:

```
$.fn.addNewTab = function (name, title, content) {
  $('ul',this).append('<li><a href="#tab-' + name + '">' + title + '</a></li>');
  $(this).append("<div id='tab-" + name + "'><a href='" + name + "'>" + content + "</a></div>");
  $(this).tabs("refresh");
};

$(function () {
  $('#tabs').tabs().addNewTab('C9JS_16.html', 'Click-a-bob', 'Click here for "Click-a-bob"');
});
```

where I've added a link in the 3rd line of code to C9JS_16.html, and changed the wording of the last argument of the anonymous function.  When you click on the tab the text 'Click here for "Click-a-bob"' is displayed, and when you click on that, it takes you to C9JS_16.html page.